# project.clj understanding some parts

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am create a web application with `duct` [lein template](https://github.com/weavejester/duct).

Now I am looking at `project.clj` to see how its works.

But I don't know if I undersant correcntly this particular part:

```
 {:dev  [:project/dev  :profiles/dev]
   :test [:project/test :profiles/test]
   :uberjar {:aot :all}
   :profiles/dev  {}
   :profiles/test {}
   :project/dev   {:dependencies [[duct/generate "0.6.1"]
                                  [reloaded.repl "0.2.1"]
                                  [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.11"]
                                  [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
                                  [eftest "0.1.1"]
                                  [kerodon "0.7.0"]]
                   :source-paths ["dev"]
                   :repl-options {:init-ns user}
                   :env {:port "3000"}}
```

For example:

Whats this `[:project/dev :profiles/dev]` mean? and why I have a `:dev` key and a `:project/dev` key.
I know it is probably about `profiles.clj` file. But I did don't really understand it right.

Maybe my question seems a little bit silly, but I hope I have been myself clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is described in [composite profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#composite-profiles):

> Sometimes it is useful to define a profile as a combination of other
>   profiles. To do this, just use a vector instead of a map as the
>   profile value. This can be used to avoid duplication:

```
{:shared {:port 9229, :protocol "https"}
 :qa [:shared {:servers ["qa.mycorp.com"]}]
 :stage [:shared {:servers ["stage.mycorp.com"]}]
 :production [:shared {:servers ["prod1.mycorp.com", "prod1.mycorp.com"]}]}
```